# How to simulate a real keyboard's keypress in Python/PyQt?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, keypress

I need to write a virtual keyboard for typing texts, I'm planning to use Python and Qt (PyQt) library for this task. problem is I don't know how to simulate KeyPress not as internal Qt event, but as simulation of a real keyboard so I could work with this keyboard as like with real one - interacting with application on my computer. I can't find anything in Qt documentation about this. So is there any way to do it through PyQt/Qt, or I need to use some Python library, and which exactly?

Comment: So you mean _not_ like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/qustions/2035310/how-can-i-simulate-user-interaction-key-press-event-in-qt)?

Comment: @figs It looks like this function work only inside application itself, it need to have receiver widget. But I need app to simulate real keyboard, so I could use app to type text for example in browser.

Comment: It is platform specific. You can't do it with Qt. On Windows you can use PyWin32 to invoke WinApi functions.

Comment: On the c++ side of Qt you can post a keypress event to the event loop to simulate a press. Maybe you can do the same in PyQt?

Comment: @Nicolas Holthaus Could you please give an example?

Comment: You may find this Qt Centre thread useful: [virtual keyboard in QT Application](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49181-virtual-keyboard-in-QT-Application). There is also this example on Qt-Apps.org: [VirtualKeyboard](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/VirtualKeyboard?content=107388). These are all C++, though, so you will obviously need to port the code to PyQt.

Comment: I wonder what's really the difference between simulate KeyPress not as internal Qt event but as simulation of a real keyboard. What do you want to achieve really? Why is the one not as good as the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that this is a PyQt question, but at the request of the OP will give a c++ example in case it helps in finding the Python solution.

On the c++ side simulating the keyboard is done by posting keypress events to the application's event loop. These may be considered 'internal Qt events', but are the exact same interface as would be received for a physical key press. They are accomplished as follows:

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (receiver, event);
```

Looking through the PyQt `QCoreApplcation` API, the `postEvent` function also exists, so it should be possible to do something analagous (unfortunately I can't offer an example as I'm unfamiliar with writting python scripts).

Comment: Thanks for help, but what is receiver in that case?

Comment: Receiver is whichever `QObject` processes the keypress event. It could be your main window, a text edit, some other widget with a keypress event filter, etc. Basically whichever `QObject` you were expecting to be the handler for the real key press.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Pyautogui is very good for this and it is stupid simple.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite("the stuff")
```

Or if you want to actually simulate pressing a literal keypress use:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keypressDown("the stuff")
pyautogui.keypressUp("the stuff")
```

Here's the documentation: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Hope this helps.